# Any good replacment for Razor Engine

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

[As you know](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/issues/42) [Razor Engine](http://razorengine.codeplex.com)  doesn't work under `MVC4`.

So I am wondering if we can use `Model object` to generate email html body in some other way.

Any clue which tool/dll we can use for it.

I really don't want to put attribute names manually and use `Replace` method if I have 100 fields in the Model...

**Sample:**

```
<div class="display-label">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>
```

Comment: Why not just use the MVC3 runtime for the email templating? It might be possible to split that code off into a separate DLL.

Comment: Where is an details related to "As u know Razor Engine doesn't work under MVC4". Could you provide more details, I need to investigate it.

Comment: @ViacheslavSmityukh Yeah if u will refer RazorEngine DLL under MVC4 project it will not work actually. Because it has internal reference to some MVC3 DLLs. The classes have been used to build RazorEngine have been refactored so this project doesn't support MVC4... :( https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/issues/42

Comment: Alternatively, you could try and see if [Spark](http://sparkviewengine.com/) or [DotLiquid](http://dotliquidmarkup.org/) support your use case

Comment: Looks like a link to this workaround is provided in the github link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647493/how-to-build-deploy-project-that-requires-multiple-versions-of-the-same-assembly/10936596#10936596

Comment: @R0MANARMY Yeah thanks... But since RazorEngine doesn't support MVC4 I need something stable...

Comment: @LexLi Sounds great bro... but I am looking for the heavy-less solution...

Comment: @lexli in the github link someone said that razor engine isn't compatible with razor 2.  Do there is a bit more to it than a simple recompile.  I think v3 of razorengine will be compatible.

Comment: RazorEngine 3.1 or above depends on Razor 2, so should be fine with MVC 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Razor Engine now has Razor 2 compatibility (introduced in 3.1)

Answer (score 1):

I've been using ActionMailer.net to generate html emails using Razor views. You can find it on NuGet or here: https://bitbucket.org/swaj/actionmailer.net/wiki/Home