# Conditionally referencing Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS dll in app.config based on SQL Client installed

Tags: c#, .net

I have created utility in .net which performs some SQL Data operation.

I have currently build application with reference to following dlls of version 10.0.0.0

- Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS
- Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap
- Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap
- Microsoft.SqlServer.PipelineHost

If I run this application from OS Windows 2008 having SQLNCLI10 it works fine.
If I run this application from OS having Windows 2012 containing SQL Client SQLNCLI11 it does not work. It requires reference to above all dlls having version 11.0.0.0

Is there any way in the app.config I can conditionally reference the dlls?

Is there any other way to overcome this issue so I can have only one application which can run of both the above environment (SQLNCLI10 & SQLNCLI11). Otherwise I will have to create two separate applications compiled with respective dlls versions.

Answer (score 0):

Check [bindingRedirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374182%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

For example, the following `assemblyIdentity` and bindingRedirect reconfigures a dependency on `Microsoft.Windows.SampleAssembly` from version 2.0.0.0 to version 2.1.0.0.

```
<dependency>
      <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity type="win32" 
name="Microsoft.Windows.SampleAssembly"  
processorArchitecture="x86" 
publicKeyToken="0000000000000000"/>
         <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.1.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This does not work when I am running on environment SQLCLI10. I want to use same exe to be used irrespective of environment and app.config conditionally load the required assembly.

Comment: [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647493/how-to-build-deploy-project-that-requires-multiple-versions-of-the-same-assembly)

Comment: I have checked the link however AssemblyResolve handler does not get fired.