# MVC plugin site with references to different versions of same dll

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dll

I'm building a website framework that supports the loading of modules. I used [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/358360/NET-4-0-ASP-NET-MVC-3-plug-in-architecture-with-e) sample as a start.

It works verly well when all plugins have the same dll's referenced. But this is prone to errors. One day someone will load a plugin that uses a newer version of a dll and then parts of that site will not work.

I would have to have the following structure

- MVC site

  - Plugin A

    - Calc.dll (V1.0)
  - Plugin B

    - Calc.dll (v1.1)

I tried to get this to work, but it did not go well. (code below). When not setting the probing private path in the web.config it can not find the provided dll's in the plugins folder though I set the privatebathbin. Error indicates that it refuses to look there. When I set the probing property in the web.config it loads just one of the versions of the dll, so one module crashes. Is it possible what I want? And if so, what is my mistake?

```
foreach (var directoryInfo in TempPluginFolder.GetDirectories())
{
     AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup();
     setup.ShadowCopyFiles = "true";
     setup.LoaderOptimization = LoaderOptimization.MultiDomain;

     setup.ApplicationBase = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase;
     setup.PrivateBinPath = directoryInfo.FullName.Replace(setup.ApplicationBase, "\\") + ";" + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.PrivateBinPath.Replace(setup.ApplicationBase, "");


     AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(directoryInfo.FullName, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence,setup);

     foreach (var fileInfo in directoryInfo.GetFiles("*.dll", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
     {
         var assemblyName = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(fileInfo.FullName);
         domain.Load(assemblyName);
     }
     ReferencePlugins(domain); (<- here I instantiate the plugin)
     AppDomain.Unload(domain);       
 }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647493/how-to-build-deploy-project-that-requires-multiple-versions-of-the-same-assembly has instructions on how to solve this.

Comment: The thing is, this depends on configuration of everyhting. As I stated, I load the plugins on first load of the site, so there is no configuration and plugin A is not aware of Plugin B.

Comment: that shouldn't matter... as long as your plugins are have the "use specific version" property set for the assembly that is causing the conflict georgiosd's answer in the linked question should work.

Comment: I did set the specific version, it only now takes the v1.0 and not the v1.1 when 1.1 is referenced.

Comment: I know this isn't an answer, but I was looking at something like this a few months back. I had some success in using this approach by Phil Haack http://bit.ly/1itqOp0

Comment: Thanks Matt. Maybe that is more the way I should go. Have plugins with versions and make updates and prerequirements... Food for thought.

Answer (score 0):

I see two (2) problems that may lead to this not working:

1. The first problem appears to state in the documentation for `AppDomain.Load(AssemblyName)` states `If a version of the requested assembly is already loaded, this method returns the loaded assembly, even if a different version is requested.`
2. The next problem is contained with the call to `AppDomain.CreateDomain` which states `o not use this method overload to create sandboxed application domains.` which looks like you are trying to do.

The call to `Load`, given the example in the docs, suggests that the assembly will be loaded into the calling domain as well as the intended domain.

Check out [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36az8x58(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36az8x58%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aehss7y0(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aehss7y0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)